# How to create EC2 instance from already uploaded VMDK image at S3 bucket using .Net SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2

How to create EC2 instance from already uploaded VMDK image at S3 bucket using .Net SDK but not Powershell commands.

Comment: Have you tried using [VM Import/Export](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/) tool of AWS? You have been downvoted because you have not done your research and also SO is for code related issues

Answer (score 0):

VMDK disk images can be imported via the **Amazon EC2 VM Import/Export service**.

See:

- [Importing a VM into Amazon EC2 Using ImportInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingVirtualMachinesinAmazonEC2.html)
- [`DiskImageImporter` in .NET SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html)